# How to change the keyboard Done button behavior?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitextfield

Alright, so my goal is that when the keyboard Done button is tapped after introducing something in a `UITextField`, it should trigger one of my actions but not dismiss the keyboard.

Right now, I've connected the `UITextField` with my action through the Did End on Exit event and each time I tap the Done button when I'm finished typing, the keyboard goes away.

Let me know if you need further clarification.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try setting `textField.delegate = self` in code, as well as conforming to the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol.  Then implement this method:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks this helped. But now I have a slightly different problem. I'm not sure if I should create a separate topic for it. So, I've placed my controller as the delegate method and overridden the textFieldShouldReturn: method, also I've placed an action to be triggered when the Done button is hit. However when I go to test it on my iPad, the app crashes... before these changes everything worker perfectly. Any thoughts?

Comment: Try to add <UITextFieldDelegate> to your controller like in my answer. Also, what is in the log?

Comment: I'm actually using a hacked version of Xcode and it doesn't show anything in the log. However I can describe what I did in the textFieldShouldReturn: method. I have placed this line of code 
[self performSelector:@selector(addButton:)]; // addButton is one of my own methods.
return NO;

and that's it. When I comment it out, the app works well

Comment: Nevermind. My mistake. I wasn't calling the method correctly. I just needed to do [self addButton]; and that's it :) But thanks anyway

Comment: What if there are multiple textfields managed by the same controller?

Comment: @ElgsQianChen the delegate method described above gives you a parameter `textField`.  Try storing all of your text fields as instance variables or assigning their `tag` property, then use a `switch` or `if` in the implementation of the method to figure out which one has returned.  Not the most elegant solution, but it should work.

Answer (score 1):

In Swift it would be :

```
//MARK: UITextFieldDelegate

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool
{
    textField.resignFirstResponder()

    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the delegate method of `UITextField`. (Set delegate of TextField to correct viewController in Interface Builder or in source)

Then, go to .h file of textField's viewcontroller:

```
@interface correctViewController(type yours) :UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
//now correctViewController "understands" our textfield.
```

Go to correctViewController.m file:

```
//Create delegate method of textField
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
    [textField resignFirstResponder]; //to hide keyboard
    return NO;
}
```

Looks like this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I was looking NOT to hide the keyboard. That's the reason I need to override this method.
P.S. It wasn't me who minused you

Comment: I didn't understand you correctlly with keyboard. Do you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `UITextFieldDelegate` Protocol Reference:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html

You can use this method to control the behavior of your keyboard:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)theTextField {
    return NO;
}
```